# Items in an array disappear mysteriously

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm currently doing a Calorie Counter project that consists on giving the user the option to firstly, add items with the respective name and number of calories, remove items or update them when clicking on an edit icon next to the item, and finally removing all items at once.

The UI will basically display all the items that the user has added (including the name and the number of calories), where each item will have an edit icon next to it, and if the icon is clicked, it will give the user the option to edit them and delete them.

I still haven't gotten to the edit part because I'm currently stuck in the delete part.

Let's say I have 3 items in the list, when I click on the edit button and then delete, everything works out fine, the html element is deleted and it looks good. If I repeat the process one more time it still works, but when I repeat the process one last time, the problem happens.

For some reason, when I hit the edit button nothing happens, I've checked and apparently the item array is completely empty, even though I only deleted 2 out of the 3 items.

I've tried everything and I've been completely stuck for 3 days straight.

```js
// Item Controller
const ItemController = function() {
  // Hard coded items
  data = [{
      name: "Hamburguer",
      id: 0,
      calories: 1000
    },
    {
      name: "Pasta",
      id: 1,
      calories: 700
    },
    {
      name: "Apple",
      id: 2,
      calories: 70
    }
  ]
  return {
    getItems: function() {
      return data;
    },
    deleteAllItems: function() {
      data.items = [];
      UIController().clearItems();
    },
    getTotalCalories: function() {
      totalCalories = 0;
      this.getItems().forEach(item => {
        totalCalories += parseInt(item.calories)
      });
      UIController().changeToTotalCalories(totalCalories);
    },
    removeSingleItem: function(item, li) {
      // Getting the index of the item
      indexItem = items.getItems().indexOf(item);
      // Deleting item from array
      items.getItems().splice(indexItem, 1);
      // Deleting li item from UI
      li.remove();
      console.log(items.getItems());
    }
  }
};

const items = ItemController();

// UI controller
const UIController = function() {
  return {
    displayItems: function(itemsPresented) {
      itemsPresented.forEach(function(item) {
        itemList = document.getElementById("item-list");
        itemList.innerHTML += `
        <li class="collection-item" id="${item.id}">
          <strong>${item.name}: </strong><em>${item.calories} calories</em>
          <a href="#" class="secondary-content">
          <i class="edit-item fa fa-pencil">
          </i>
          </a>
        </li>
        `;
      })
    },
    clearItems: function() {
      itemList = document.getElementById("item-list");
      itemList.innerHTML = "";
      items.getTotalCalories();
    },
    changeToTotalCalories: function(totalCalories) {
      document.querySelector(".total-calories").textContent = totalCalories;
    },
  }
}
const uiCtrl = UIController();

// So when the page loads, the hard coded items can be represented
uiCtrl.displayItems(items.getItems());

// To delete all the items at once
clearAllBtn = document.querySelector(".clear-btn");

clearAllBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  items.deleteItems();

  e.preventDefault();
})

// Getting the li element (The one that has all the hard-coded items)
itemList = document.getElementById("item-list");

itemList.addEventListener("click", e => {
  // Checking if the user is clicking the Edit Icon
  if (e.target.classList.contains("edit-item")) {
    items.getItems().forEach(item => {
      li = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;
      // Getting the item that has the edit icon that the user clicked
      if (item.id === parseInt(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.id)) {
        // Putting the name and the calories of the item that is being edited in the input fields
        document.getElementById("item-name").value = item.name;
        document.getElementById("item-calories").value = item.calories;

        // Changing the buttons so when the user edits an item, they have the options Update and Delete
        document.querySelector(".add-btn").style.display = "none";
        document.querySelector(".update-btn").style.display = "block";
        document.querySelector(".delete-btn").style.display = "block";
        document.querySelector(".back-btn").style.display = "none";

        // If the user clicks the delete button
        document.querySelector(".delete-btn").addEventListener("click", e => {

          // Changing all the buttons back to normal
          document.querySelector(".add-btn").style.display = "block";
          document.querySelector(".update-btn").style.display = "none";
          document.querySelector(".delete-btn").style.display = "none";
          document.querySelector(".back-btn").style.display = "block";

          // Clearing out the input fields
          document.getElementById("item-name").value = "";
          document.getElementById("item-calories").value = "";

          // Deleting item
          items.removeSingleItem(item, li);

          // Updating the calories 
          items.getTotalCalories();

          e.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper blue">
    <div class="container">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo center">
          Tracalorie
        </a>
      <ul class="right">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="clear-btn btn blue lighten-3">
              Clear All
            </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<br>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Form Card -->
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-content">
      <span class="card-title">
          Add Meal / Food Item
        </span>
      <form class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="text" id="item-name" placeholder="Add item">
            <label for="item-name">Meal</label>
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <input type="text" id="item-calories" placeholder="Add calories">
            <label for="item-calories">Calories</label>
          </div>
          <button class="add-btn btn blue darken-3"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
            Add Meal</button>
          <button style="display: none;" class="update-btn btn orange" display=><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
            Update Meal</button>
          <button style="display: none;" class="delete-btn btn red"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i>
            Delete Meal</button>
          <button class="back-btn btn grey pull-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>
            Back</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Calorie Count -->
  <h3 class="center-align">Total Calories: <span class="total-calories">
      0
    </span></h3>

  <!-- Item list -->
  <ul id="item-list" class="collection">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you add an eventListener to the delete button every single time a user clicks on the edit pencil. You never remove these eventListeners. So when the first edit is done, there is one delete event and one items gets deleted. The next time a user clicks on the edit button, a second event gets added to the same html element, thus two items gets deleted (both events will trigger one after the other). This becomes apparent when your hardcoded list would contain 10 items, you would see 1,2,3 and lastly 4 items disappear. I suggest you look into resetting/removing eventlisteners.

Comment: Okay, just fixed it, I had to put the Delete Event Listener outside of the other event listener. Lesson learned, never put an event listener inside of another event listener!